# How to Convert System Time to Certain Timezone in Unity Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I would like to get my android device's local system time with Unity C#, then convert it to Eastern Standard Time as point of reference for various things inside my game. Which syntax should I use to convert the timezone?

I've tried using the TimeZoneInfo class.

```
DateTime appStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(System.DateTime.Now, "US/Eastern");
```

I expect it to return the Eastern Time, but it returns an error "DirectoryNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registry information are different on Android.

Use this.

```
DateTime appStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(System.DateTime.Now, "America/New_York");
```

You may check a list of [Iana Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that are different from Windows Time Zone. You might also read the [Timezone Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

There's also a library to do the conversion: [Time Zone Converter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/).